# changing the title of a popover with bootstrap and jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

here's the html for the link, i.e.:

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size: 3em; color: #222" class="popover-test" id="directNavPrev" data-title="Previous Result Row" data-content="Previous Result Row">
&laquo;</a>
```

yes, i'm calling .popover() to initialize and the popover works just fine. i can get the content to update with no problem. just not the title. i've tried "prev.data('title','new title')" and even tried to re-init "prev.popover({title:'new title'});" with no dice... thanks.

```
 function SetDirectNavigationPlaceholder() {
    //debugger;
    var item = $("#movementType :selected").val();
    var direct = $('#directNavigation');
    var prev = $('#directNavPrev');
    var next = $('#directNavNext');
    switch (item) {
        case "result":
            $('#bookTypeSection').addClass('hide');
            direct.val('Result Row from 1 - 150');
            prev.attr('data-title', "Previous Result Row");
            next.attr('data-title', "Next Result Row");
            prev.attr('data-content', "Check it! this will contain the information for the previous result<table><tr><td>blah</td><td>blah</td></tr><tr><td>blah</td><td>blah</td></tr><tr><td>blah</td><td>blah</td></tr><tr><td>blah</td><td>blah</td></tr></table>");
            next.attr('data-content', "Check it! this will contain the information for the next result<table><tr><td>blah</td><td>blah</td></tr></table>");
            break;
        case "instrument":
            $('#bookTypeSection').addClass('hide');
            direct.val('Instrument #');
            prev.attr('data-title', "Previous Instrument #");
            next.attr('data-title', "Next Instrument #");
            prev.attr('data-content', "Check it! this will contain the information for the previous <b>instrument</b><table><tr><td>blah</td><td>blah</td></tr></table>");
            next.attr('data-content', "Check it! this will contain the information for the next <b>instrument</b><table><tr><td>blah</td><td>blah</td></tr></table>");
            break;
        case "bookpage":
            $('#bookTypeSection').removeClass('hide');
            direct.val('Book/Page');
            prev.attr('data-title', "Previous Book/Page");
            next.attr('data-title', "Next Book/Page");
            prev.attr('data-content', "Check it! this will contain the information for the previous <b>book/page</b><table><tr><td>blah</td><td>blah</td></tr></table>");
            next.attr('data-content', "Check it! this will contain the information for the next <b>book/page</b><table><tr><td>blah</td><td>blah</td></tr></table>");
            break;
    }
    direct.css('color', '#aaa').not('#directNavigationHeader');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that cat skinned!

Here's the deal. It appears that in the bootstrap.js file there is no method for getTitle() even though it's calling. So I added it. Enjoy.

```
/* NOTE: POPOVER EXTENDS BOOTSTRAP-TOOLTIP.js
 ========================================== */

Popover.prototype = $.extend({}, $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.prototype, {
  constructor: Popover, setContent: function () {
  //debugger;

  var $tip = this.tip()
    , title = this.getTitle() // didn't exist
    , content = this.getContent()

  $tip.find('.popover-title')[this.isHTML(title) ? 'html' : 'text'](title)
  $tip.find('.popover-content > *')[this.isHTML(content) ? 'html' : 'text'](content)

  $tip.removeClass('fade top bottom left right in')
}

, hasContent: function () {
  return this.getTitle() || this.getContent()
}

 , getContent: function () {
  var content
    , $e = this.$element
    , o = this.options

  content = $e.attr('data-content')
    || (typeof o.content == 'function' ? o.content.call($e[0]) : o.content)

  return content
}

 , getTitle: function () { // does now
  var title
    , $t = this.$element
    , n = this.options

  title = $t.attr('data-title')
    || (typeof n.title == 'function' ? n.title.call($t[0]) : n.title)

  return title
}

, tip: function () {
  if (!this.$tip) {
      this.$tip = $(this.options.template)
  }
  return this.$tip
}

})
```

for some reason I can't grab the actual "title" attribute so you'll have to use "data-title" if you want to change it.

Comment: The `getTitle` method of the popover is inherited from the `tooltip` constructor. So there _is_ a `getTitle` method that you are overriding.

Answer (score 21):

The easiest way to do it is this one :

```
     var newTitle = "Here's my new title";
     $('#MyExample').attr('data-original-title', newTitle);
```

Hope it helped !

Comment: That little nasty snippet I was looking for, for quite a while, thanks Yann, my friend!!

Comment: Thank alot ! I found it by myself since I noticed nobody was talking about it

Comment: Why does Bootstrap not provide documentation for this, or a number of other basic features?  For example, why is there no API command to obtain the popover element when it is displayed?

Comment: Worked for me, it wasn't working when setting 'data-title' so I'm glad I found this answer

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Twitter-bootstrap doesn't keep a `div` around for targeting the popover so changing the title by changing the header isn't possible. However, [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664051/when-using-twitters-bootstrap-how-can-i-change-a-popovers-content) might help.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jackpines/rBWcQ/35/) that you can, uh, fiddle with.

And the code for those who can't fiddle with it. :-)

HTML:

```
<div style="padding-top: 45px;">
    <a data-content="Original Content for Popover" data-original-title="Popover Title" data-placement="right" href="#" class="btn danger" id="popover-link" rel="popover">Rollover</a>
</div>​
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#popover-link').popover({title: function() {return 'new title';}});
$('#popover-link').attr("data-content", "New Content for Popover");
$('#popover-link').setTitle('new title');​
```

Comment: that is dirty. you know what i like.

Comment: that was, in fact, not a fix.

Comment: Awesome! I'm just going to modify the JS and move on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
$("#mylink").data()["bs.popover"].config.title = "New Ttile";
$("#mylink").data()["bs.popover"].config.content = "<p>New Content</p>";
```

or

```
$("#mylink").data("bs.popover").config.title = "New Ttile";
$("#mylink").data("bs.popover").config.content = "<p>New Content</p>";
```