# Angularjs not interpolating title for Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I am trying to use a Bootstrap Popover in an AngularJS ngRepeat directive. The problem is the title attribute isn't being interpolated. How can I resolve this issue?

**View**

```
<div ng-app="app" id="ng-app">
<ul ng-controller="Main">
    <li ng-repeat="i in items" data-toggle="popover" title="{{ i.title }}" <!-- Title isn't interpolated so Popover doesn't render a title -->
        data-content="Events: {{ day.events.length }}"
        init-popover>{{ i.data }}</li>
</ul>
```

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Main', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.items = [
        { title: 'Title 1', data: 'lorem' },
        { title: 'Title 2', data: 'ipsum' },
    ];
}]);

app.directive('initPopover', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.$last){
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({container: 'ul'});
    }
  };
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uqxr4apy/3/)

Comment: Hello. I appreciate that you included a fiddle, but it isn't clear what the problem is. Can you improve your fiddle so that it says "Here is what I would like to happen: X. As you can see, Y is happening."

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I updated the Fiddle.

Comment: I'd suggest [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) here, but see my answer for a solution using the current plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it work but it's pretty ugly, here is my solution

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Main', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.items = [        
        { title: 'Title 1', data: 'Test in ngRepeat' },
        { title: 'Title 2', data: 'Test in ngRepeat' },
    ];
}]);

app.directive('initPopover', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (scope.$last) {
      attrs.$observe('title', function () {
          $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({container: 'ul'});
      });
      }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `title="{{i.title}}"`, but `ng-attr-title="{{i.title}}"`...

Comment: Sorry, your fiddle isn't clear to me, too: what is your "desired result"? However, for AngularJS to interpolate title attribute, you *must* use `ng-attr-title`, and *not* `title`...

Comment: The desired result is for the title of the Popover to be driven a value in the scope object. It currently is not being interpolated. If I try to use `ng-attr-title`, it is not rendered in the popover. I will update the fiddle to show this.

Comment: I see, sorry, I didn't understand what you meant. Sorry, I never used popovers, so can't help you here... More, I see title is interpolated by AngularJS as well as ng-attr-title... I am quite sure some time ago (and angular versions ago) it was not the case... :-(

Comment: Popover requires the `title` attribute to be set in order for it to render a title for the popover but it's just not interpolating.

Comment: I remember, now... :-) You have to use `ng-attr-title` when you want *dynamical* titles (i.e.: titles following the model, and not set statically on page load...).

Comment: It looks like I'm  going to have to override the `Tooltip.getTitle` method to handle `ng-attr-title`... just not sure how to do this.

Comment: `ng-attr-title` is for _HTML titles_ (frequently rendered as tooltips). This is a little tricky because the Bootstrap plugin looks at the same attribute as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I'm using bootstrap v3.3.6 and Angular v1.5.0

Adding attribute **data-original-title="{{someTitle}}"** fixed the problem.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="{{someTitle}}" data-original-title="{{someTitle}}" data-content="Some Content">Click to toggle popover</button>
```

Also, as bootstrap requires, call .popover() in directive

```
module.directive('myDir', ['jQuery', function (jQuery) {
    return {
        link: function () {
            jQuery('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) for native Angular directives instead of Bootstrap's jQuery version. They're a lot easier to work with in an Angular project.

**Edit:** If you can't do that, here's a solution:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items" data-toggle="popover" data-ng-attr-popover_title="{{ i.title }}" 
            data-content="Popover Content"
            init-popover>{{ i.data }}</li>
```

With a small change to the directive:

```
app.directive('initPopover', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.$last){
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ container: 'ul', title: attrs.popoverTitle });
    }
  };
```

`ng-attr-popup_title` will create an HTML attribute called `popupTitle` on the element with the Angular syntax inside `{{}}` parsed correctly. Then, in the directive, we can just examine that attribute to set the popover title.

Fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uqxr4apy/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `$timeout` to directive will solve your problem.
$timeout will gets call when last element of ng-repeat rendered on UI & run `$digest` cycle.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('initPopover', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) {
            $timeout(function() {
                angular.element('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                    container: 'ul'
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqxr4apy/13/)

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the knowledge base here. Here's the angular way, in case anyone needs. I based my solution on [Mark Coleman's PopOver tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1360/bootstrap-popover-using-angularjs-compile-service), and of course what has been contributed by Nate Barbettini.

My situation was I have a nested ng-repeat over items in items, so I need to have a title for my popup that is based on an array stored in a scope, while the content of the popup is from another array stored in the array of the scope.

I added `ng-attr-title` to my HTML element, like so:

```
 <div pop-over items='week.items' ng-attr-title="{{'Week number:'+ week.week}}">  Total sales this week : {{week.sales}}</div>
```

Then, in my directive, I followed mostly what Mark Coleman did.

```
    angular.module('vegadirectives', [])
.directive('popOver', function ($compile, $templateCache) {

var itemsTemplate = "<ul class='popper'><li ng-repeat='thing in items track by $index'>";
itemsTemplate+=" <i class='fa fa-square' ng-class=";
itemsTemplate+="{purple:thing.color==='purple','orange':thing.color==='orange','white':thing.color==='white','pink':thing.color==='pink','red':thing.color==='red','green':thing.color==='green','yellow':thing.color==='yellow'}";
itemsTemplate+="></i>  {{thing.model}} - {{thing.qty}}</li></ul>";
    var getTemplate = function () {
        var template=itemsTemplate;
        return template;
    }
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true, 
        template: "<span ng-transclude></span>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var popOverContent;


            if (scope.items) {
                var html = getTemplate();
                popOverContent = $compile(html)(scope);                    
                var options = {
                    trigger:'click',
                    content: popOverContent,
                    placement: "right",
                    html: true,
                    title:scope.title


                };
                if (scope.$last) {

                }
                $(element).popover(options);
            }
        },
        scope: {
            items: '=',
           title:'@'
        }
    };
});
```

Explanation:

To fill up my popover with a list of items, with some fancy color square to indicate different types of items, I created a chunk of HTML code. This chunk named itemsTemplate will be used by $compile to create the popover content with scope.  I think the usage is $compile(htmlstring)(scope).

Next comes the standard stuff for options settings for the popover.
For the interpolation of scope with title, I specified the option `title:` with `scope.title`. Then, in the `scope:` option way down at the end, the two scope elements are specified with `'='` and `'@'`.

So, the `title:scope.title` refers or binds to `scope: {items:'=', title:'@' }`, and the `title:'@'` is the attributes of the title in the HTML, which is `ng-attrs-title={{week.week}}`, where week is from the outer ng-repeat loop.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After finding this answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17864868/2379762, I tried data-original-title={{i.title}}, and it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/f1tjj8x5/

```
<li ng-repeat="i in items" data-toggle="popover" data-original-title="{{ i.title }}" 
        data-content="Popover Content"
        init-popover>{{ i.data }}</li>
```