# Bootstrap popover content cannot changed dynamically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I use the code as follows:

```
$(".reply").popover({
  content: "Loading...",
  placement: "bottom"
});

$(".reply").popover("toggle");
```

which creates the popover and its content correctly. I want to load a new data into the popover without closing the popover.

I've tried the following:

```
var thisVal = $(this);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  url: "Getdes",
  data: { id: ID }
}).success(function(data) {
  thisVal.attr("data-content", data);
});
```

After this call the data in the element is changed but not in the popover which is shown.

How should i do this?

Comment: you can also access the popover's inner element and change the content there via jQuery, e.g. $(".popover-content").html(my_new_content)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you grab the popover instance like this:

```
var popover = $('.reply').data('bs.popover');
```

Then, to redraw the popover, use the `.setContent()` method:

```
popover.setContent();
```

I found out browsing the source: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/popover.js

So, in your example, try:

```
thisVal.attr('data-content',data).data('bs.popover').setContent();
```

**Update**

The `setContent()` method also removes the placement class, so you should do:

```
var popover = thisVal.attr('data-content',data).data('bs.popover');
popover.setContent();
popover.$tip.addClass(popover.options.placement);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/44RvK

Comment: ya it works but the design of the popover changed after redrawing is there any way to keep the existing design

Comment: Yea, it seems to remove the placement class too, so just add the class again. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/44RvK/

Comment: The popover is not re-positioned after changing the content to something that takes up more space: http://jsfiddle.net/g4kZS/ - only when it is closed and opened again.

Comment: This way have too many side effect, see my answer below, much easier and better in my opinion

Comment: the source file is https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/popover.js

Comment: recently the data tag for popover was changed, so you need to use .data('bs-popover') instead of .data('popover')

Comment: .data('bs.popover') instead of .data('popover') in the latest version

Comment: Updated this to bs.popover.

Comment: If you need to reposition the offset `calculated_offset = popover.getCalculatedOffset( popover.options.placement, popover.getPosition(),  popover.$tip[0].offsetWidth,  popover.$tip[0].offsetHeight); popover.applyPlacement(calculated_offset, popover.options.placement);` A little bit messy...

Comment: Using bootstrap 4, there is no problem with the placement being lost but you need to call popover.update() after popover.setContent() to reposition the popover according to the content.

Comment: real heroes don't wear capes.

Answer (score 77):

Yes you can, in fact the easiest way haven't been suggested yet.

Here's my way ->

```
    var popover = $('#example').data('bs.popover');
    popover.options.content = "YOUR NEW TEXT";
```

popover is an object if you want to know more about it, try to do console.log(popover) after you define it to see how you can use it after !

**EDIT**

As of Bootstrap 4 alpha 5, the data structure is a bit different. You'll need to use `popover.config.content` instead of `popover.options.content`

Thanks to @kfriend for the comment

Comment: it's working fine, just set content as Yann specified then call popover.show(). that's the best answer "short, no side effects to counter like some of other answers"

Comment: I used this for `popover.options.placement = 'bottom'`, thanks Yann!

Comment: .data('bs.popover') instead of .data('popover') in the latest version

Comment: Worked for me in BS3; quick n' easy. I think it's the best answer here.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, no messing around with classes or anything - simples.

Comment: As of Bootstrap 4 alpha 5, the data structure is a bit different. You'll need to use `popover.config.content` instead of `popover.options.content`.

Answer (score 22):

In bootstrap 3:

```
if($el.data('bs.popover')) {
    $el.data('bs.popover').options.content = "New text";
}
$el.popover('show');
```

Answer (score 17):

This answer from 2012 does not work with Bootstrap 3 popovers.  I extracted a working solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459042/can-i-use-dynamic-content-in-a-bootstrap-popover):

> $("#popover").attr('data-content', 'new content');

Comment: This is absolutely the only way I got this to work on a specific popover with bootstrap 3. For some reason, $("#popover").data('content', 'new content'); does not work so I originally ignored this solution. Thanks!

Comment: yup, on bs3, this was my only option on dynamic changes - thanks

Answer (score 10):

Most of these solutions actually seem hacky to me.  Bootstrap standard docs have a method `destroy` that can be used. So, on change of content via some event you can simply destroy and then recreate content.

```
.popover('destroy')
```

This properly dynamically loads, refreshes and re-renders the content of the popover.

Comment: Creating the popover isn't that complicated and I have also had good luck with using destroy and then re-creating the popover.

Comment: Here's a fiddle that can load dynamic data, but its flashes the popover.
http://jsfiddle.net/dbuj2Lnt/1/

Answer (score 4):

**SIMPLE SOLUTION**

You can try with this :

`//Bootstrap v3.3.7 
 var popoverEl = $("#popover");
 popoverEl.attr("data-content", "NEW CONTENT");
 popoverEl.popover("show");`

Thanks.

Comment: This is the correct answer for Bootstrap 3.x. No need to use `setContent()`.This works with a string or HTML content.

Comment: Yes, I agree with this for Bootstrap 3.x

Comment: calling `popoverEl.popover("show")` makes my already visible popover go away :-(.  I just wanted it to rerender correctly in the right location with the new data.  I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7.

Comment: it should be add with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974559/bootstrap-popover-toggle-only-show. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem using [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210578/david) and [@Sujay sreedhar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2077829/sujay-sreedhar)'s answer, but if the popover is visible during the new content is loaded, the popover needs to be repositioned:

```
var popover = thisVal.attr('data-content',data).data('popover');
popover.setContent();
popover.$tip.addClass(popover.options.placement);
// if popover is visible before content has loaded
if ($(".reply").next('div.popover:visible').length){
    // reposition
    popover.show();
}
```

If it is not repositioned and the new content has e.g. a different height, the popover will expand downwards and the arrow will be off target!

Also, when the button is clicked afterwards it will re-open the popover instead of closing it. The above code solves, that problem too.

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/whFv6/

(My edit was rejected, so I thought I'd post it here..)

Answer (score 1):

After the popover has been correctly initialized, you can directly use jquery to replace the `class="popover-content"` element:

```
$(".popover-content").html('a nice new content')
```

Comment: I like the idea but how would you update the content of a specific popover, if you have several initialized on a page?

Answer (score 1):

you can just pass the title as function

```
var content = 'Loading...'

function dynamicContent(){
  return content
}
$(".reply").popover({
  content: dynamicContent,
  placement: "bottom"
});

$(".reply").popover("toggle");
```

and then change the variable content dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-content='<div id="myPopover">content</div>'>click</button>
$('#myPopover').html('newContent')
```

This is a very clean way.

Comment: +1 That totally made my day, used within the    $( 'a[data-toggle="popover"]' ).on('inserted.bs.popover', function () {}); thing.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an async popover for bootstrap 3.1.1. I just called it `popoverasync`. Here is a demonstration:

[async popover demo](http://www.dankemper.net/t3/examples/bootstrap-async-popover/)

You can download the source of the demo here:

[demo source](http://www.dankemper.net/t3/examples/bootstrap-async-popover.zip)

The trick, for me, was to write the `getContent` method of this async popover so the user's javascript function to retrieve the content will be invoked, but `getContent` will return a wait animation, synchronously, back to the caller of `getContent`. This way, the popover has content either way. First, while the user waits, and finally when the content arrives. What I am referring to can be found within `extensions.js` in the demo source:

Hope this helps you!

Dan

Comment: I used the async pop-over and found out that if I am using ajax, the ajax is fired two times. First during .hasContent() check and second during .setContent(). Is there anyway to stop this?

Comment: Please create a Github repo to log issues.

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML

```html
<a data-toggle="popover" popover-trigger="outsideClick" title="Indicadores" data-content="" data-html="true" class="Evaluar" id="alun codigo"><span><i class="fa fa-check"></i>algun nombre</span></a>
```

#### JQUERY

```js
$('a.Evaluar').on('click', function () {
    var a=$(this);//.attr('data-content', "mañana");
    $.ajax({
        url: "../IndicadorControlador?accion=BuscarPorProceso&cP=24",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    })
            .done(function (response) {
                //alert("done. ");
                var ind = "";
                $(response).each(function (indice, elemento) {
                    //alert(elemento.strIdentificador);
                    //console.log('El elemento con el índice ' + indice + ' contiene ' + elemento.strIdentificador.toString());
                    ind += '<a href=#>'+elemento.strIdentificador.toString()+'</a>';
                });
              $(a).attr('data-content', ind);
            })
            .fail(function () {
                sweetAlert("ERROR!", " Algo salió mal en el controlador!", "error");
            })
            .complete(function () {
            });

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When a popover is enabled, it retains its previous version(if it was created already) even if the data is change. You need to destroy the previous version to allow for the new popover to be created again.
In Bootstrap 4.x do it by

```
.popover('dispose')
```

do it whenever there is a change in data through an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

**For Boostrap v4.3**

The following code update the popover content just before it is displayed:

```
// When the popover is show
$('.my-popover').on('show.bs.popover', function () {
  // Update popover content
  $(this).attr('data-content', 'New content');
})
```

Test online on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/xo2j1u7n/279/).

Comment: Popover doesn't even toggle in the fiddle & this will not update it realtime, it will work when the popover is closed & open again.

Comment: Here's a solution I'm using. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62228583/5420070

Answer (score 0):

With `bootstrap 4.6` I am using this code to update it:

```
$("#disk-usage-details").attr("data-content", "your new content to here");
```

all others did not work for me.

Comment: Last solution on the page - of course :) For me this also was the only solution I could get to work with BS 4.6

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap v5

```js
var element = document.getElementById('popElement');
var popover = bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance(element, { trigger: 'hover' });
element.addEventListener('shown.bs.popover', () => {
   // call your api, then:
   popover.setContent({ '.popover-body': 'updated content' });
}, {once : true});
```