# Bootstrap popover.toggle() only show

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am trying to integrate a twitter bootstrap popover ; I am forced to use the javascript API, because some dynamic elements are loaded via Ajax and should react too.

Basically, here is a example tag that should react :

```
<a data-container="#appConfigDialog" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" 
   data-content="&lt;img src=&quot;URL&quot; /&gt;"
   data-html="true" href="#" 
   class="popoverFileSee btn btn-default">See</a>
```

URL is by the way replaced by the correct URL

And my JS :

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".popoverFileSee", function() {
    $( this ).popover( "toggle" );      
    return false;
});
```

Here is the behavior I would like to achieve :

- When first click, the popover shows
- When a click occurs for an opened popover, it should close it

Isn't it the aim of "toggle" ? Is there something wrong in this code sample, or should I check elsewhere in my application ?

Thanks

EDIT : For now, it always show the popover, even if it is already opened
Weird thing : if I add `alert( "test" );` in my callback function, then it works..

Comment: What behaviour does it currently have?

Comment: It always shows the popover, event it's already opened

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Finally found the answer myself.. ;)
I simply had to add an attribute to my link : `data-trigger="manual"`

Answer (score 1):

`Remove` the `toggle` from `popover function` without using `click event` like,

```
$(".popoverFileSee").popover();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b9b6U/)

**Updated,** If you need to `add click event` the after this you can add which is `independent` to `popover` like,

```
$(".popoverFileSee").popover();
$(".popoverFileSee").on('click',function(){
   // your ajax code here
});
```

Comment: As I said, I need to use the `click event` because I load some elements with Ajax ;)

Comment: Yep, that's not the thing ; when I speak about "loading some elements with ajax", I mean "elements that have a popover button"
One solution could be to call `$( ".popoverFileSee" ).popover()` each time a new element is loaded, but I prefer to simply add a `click event` that would automatically do it ; see my answer to solve the problem with this context ;)