# How to parse value from popover to textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to parse value from dropdown box inside a popover to the input text. I can make it pop but cannot insert the selected value. I don't need a select in a popup for some reasons.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Choose your option</h3>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" data-placement="auto" data-toggle="popover">
</div>

<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
  <div class="input-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="select">
      <option>one</option>
      <option>two</option>
      option>
    </select>
    <a href="#" id="optBtn" class="btn btn-primary input-group-addon">OK</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
  html: true,
  content: function() {
    return $('#popover-content').html();
  }
});
var selectVar = $('#select').val();
$('#optBtn').click(function() {
  $('#input').val(selectVar);
})
```

Fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/723exh1g/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were binding the element in wrong way. Try this -

```
$(document).on('click','#optBtn',function() {//can be hide after select
    var selectVar = $('#select').find('option:selected').val();
    alert(selectVar)
    $('#input').val(selectVar);
})
```

Comment: Note just `var selectVar = $('#select').val()` will work fine here.

Comment: @nikhil_gandhi yes it's woking! How can I hide the popover after a button clicked? I'tried '$('#popover-content').hide();' but it's not working. => https://jsfiddle.net/723exh1g/6/

Comment: I think you'll have to open popover manually. Check this out - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974559/bootstrap-popover-toggle-only-show

Comment: You can use `$('.popover').hide();` to hide the popup.

Comment: No it won't hide as he has not opened the popover manually. I have tried using hide.

Comment: @Wilf Is the button you are mentioning is "OK" button in popup or a html button available on the page?

Comment: This is the wrong way to binding the click event in whole document, so we need to delegate the events, whatever we want,
so following.

Comment: @PhaniKumarM your solution is working! How to accept yours then :P

Comment: @Wilf If my comment helped you then you can upvote my comment.

Comment: @KunvarSingh What do you mean? No this isn't the wrong way to do that, using `.on()` is encouraged.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek he has problem with $(document), as this will search in whole document. I used document in my answer because I didn't bother to look after parent class while giving answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can try on this.

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
  html: true,
  content: function() {
    return $('#popover-content').html();
  }
}).parent().delegate('#optBtn', 'click', function() {
    var selectVar = $('#select').val();
     $('#input').val(selectVar);
     alert(selectVar);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @nikhil_gandhi and @PhaniKumarM for the helps. The final code as below:

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
  html: true,
  content: function() {
    return $('#popover-content').html();
  }
});
$(document).on('click','#optBtn',function() {//can be hide after select
    var selectVar = $('#select').find('option:selected').val();
    $('#input').val(selectVar);
    $('.popover').hide();
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/723exh1g/17/