# Pass value form popover to input

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Is there a chance that this code [How to parse value from popover to textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951818/how-to-parse-value-from-popover-to-textbox/47811033#47811033) will work also with Bootstrap 4 beta? I tried to modify this code, but can't figure it out. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind the answer to the [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45951880/3897122) Bootstrap 3 variant still stands and it is working in Bootstrap 4 too. I've created my version of that in a Bootstrap 4 environment in the snippet below.

See some explanation in the comments.

```js
$(function() {
    var popover = $('[data-toggle="popover"]');

    // Popover init
    popover.popover({
        'content'   : $('#popover-content').html(),
        'html'      : true,
        'placement' : 'auto',
    });

    // Listen to delegated 'change' events, filtered to `.popover select`
    $(document).on('change', '.popover select', function() {
        // `this` is the <select> now
        // No need to find :selected, use $select.val()
        var selected = $(this).val();
        
        $('#input').val(selected);
        popover.popover('hide');
    });
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" class="form-control" data-toggle="popover" placeholder="placeholder"/>

<div id="popover-content" style="display:none;">
    <select>
        <option>Please select</option>
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:** to address click event and support multiple input fields.

The first snippet below follows the logic of the previous code with the `change` event, but listens to the `click` event of an additional “submit” button now. In order to make this work, the selector of the delegated event listener had to be changed, and the code handler had to be adjusted accordingly.

```js
$(function() {
    var popover = $('[data-toggle="popover"]');

    // Popover init
    popover.popover({
        'content'   : $('#popover-content').html(),
        'html'      : true,
        'placement' : 'auto',
    });

    // Listen to delegated 'click' events, filtered to `.popover`
    $(document).on('click', '.popover', function(event) {
        // `this` is the '.popover' now
        // `event.target` is the clicked element
        // If clicked element was not a `.btn` then return
        if (!$(this).find('.btn').filter(event.target).length) {
            return;
        }

        // Finding <select> in popover and grab its selected value
        var selected = $(this).find('select').val();
        
        $('#input').val(selected);
        popover.popover('hide');
    });
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" class="form-control" data-toggle="popover" placeholder="placeholder"/>

<div id="popover-content" style="display:none;">
    <select>
        <option>Please select</option>
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">OK</a>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

While this is still simple with couple of lines of code, it is hard to extend to be used with more than one input fields as `$('#input')` is hardcoded in the handler. This was the case in the first example as well.

So finally I come up with another approach that binds the `click` event with the `.one()` jQuery method to the popover itself. With this it is possible to relatively reference multiple input fields and the corresponding popover.

```js
$(function() {
    var inputs = $('[data-toggle="popover"]');

    // Popover init
    inputs.popover({
        'content'   : $('#popover-content').html(),
        'html'      : true,
        'placement' : 'auto',
    });

    inputs.on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
        // 'aria-describedby' is an attribute set by Bootstrap indicationg the #id of popover
        var popover = $('#' + $(this).attr('aria-describedby'));

        // jQuery.one(events [, selector ] [, data ], handler);
        // Passing references to <select> and <input> with `data` to `handler`
        popover.one('click', '.btn', {
                '$select'    : popover.find('select'),
                '$input'     : $(this),
            }, function(event) {
                // `event.data.$select` === `popover.find('select')`, the <select> in the popover
                var selected = event.data.$select.val();

                event.data.$input
                    .val(selected)// set the value of <input>
                    .popover('hide');// hide the popover
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-toggle="popover" placeholder="placeholder 1"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-toggle="popover" placeholder="placeholder 2"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-toggle="popover" placeholder="placeholder 3"/>

<div id="popover-content" style="display:none;">
    <select>
        <option>Please select</option>
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
        <option value="maybe">Maybe</option>
    </select>

    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">OK</a>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OK. this is working, but if I want to keep submit button and function will be listening on 'click' handler?

Comment: @tomas Check the updated answer. It addresses the `click` handler topic and suggests a new approach that works with multiple inputs as well.