# jQuery removeClass seems not to work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-popover

I am trying to removeClass from "li" but it doesn't work. Here is my function:

```
function setStore($s, id, name) {
    //alert("length: " + $s.parents('ul.popup-cbo-menu').find('li.selected').length);
    $s.parents('ul.popup-cbo-menu').find('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
    //alert("length: " + $s.parents('ul.popup-cbo-menu').find('li.selected').length);

    //$s.parent('li').addClass('selected');
    $('#cboStores').val(name);
}
```

I can confirm that the "selected" is removed by putting alert. But for some reason, it doesn't affect the actual "li".

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/87xswem7/9/.
However, but for some reason, jsFiddle is unable to find setStore() function.

Here is how I create the popover:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cboStores").popover({
        viewport: 'body',
        trigger: 'click',
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: true,
        content: '<ul class="popup-cbo-menu">' +
                 '   <li><a href="#" onclick="setStore($(this), -1, \'All Stores\')">All Stores</a></li>' + 
                 '   <li class="selected"><a href="#" onclick="setStore($(this), 1, \'My Foot\')">My Foot</a></li>' +
                 '   <li><a href="#" onclick="setStore($(this), 2, \'My Foot 1\')">My Foot 1</a></li>' +
                 '</ul>',
        template: '<div class="popover cont-popup-cbo-menu" role="tooltip">' +
                  '   <div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3>' +
                  '   <div class="popover-content"></div>' +
                  '</div>'
    }).blur(function () {
        $(this).popover('hide');
    });
});
```

And here is my input box in html:

```
<input type="text" id="cboStores" value="My Foot" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem you're having is that you're trying to use your setStore function to modify the content of a popover assuming that it exists normally in the DOM:

```
function setStore($s, id, name) {
    //alert("length: " + $s.parents('ul.popup-cbo-menu').find('li.selected').length);
    $s.parents('ul.popup-cbo-menu').find('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
    //alert("length: " + $s.parents('ul.popup-cbo-menu').find('li.selected').length);

    //$s.parent('li').addClass('selected');
    $('#cboStores').val(name);
}
```

However, the content of your popover, as defined, does not exist in the DOM the way you expect. The content is actually a property of the popover and can be logged as such:

```
console.log($("#cboStores").data('bs.popover').options.content)
```

Now, in order to do what you would like, you will have to be able to dynamically modify the contents of the popover.

Here is a post I referenced to do just that: [Bootstrap popover content cannot changed dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564782/bootstrap-popover-content-cannot-changed-dynamically)

So, what I did is remove the HTML content semantics from your javascript and I put it directly into the HTML to be manipulated by the javascript:

```
<input type="text" id="cboStores" placeholder="Select Store" value="My Foot" style="width:150px;height:30px;" />

<div id="popoverContent" class="hidden">
    <ul class="popup-cbo-menu">
        <li><a href="#" onclick="setStore($(this), -1, 'All Stores')">All Stores</a></li>
        <li class="selected"><a href="#" onclick="setStore($(this), 1, 'My Foot')">My Foot</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="setStore($(this), 2, 'My Foot 1')">My Foot 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Notice I wrapped everything in a hidden div which will be used to reference the popover content. Now, the new setStore function looks like this:

```
function setStore($s, id, name) {                                                               
    $('#popoverContent').find('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $('#popoverContent').find('a').filter(function(){
        return $(this).text() === $s[0].innerHTML;
    }).parent().addClass('selected');
    $('#cboStores').val(name);
    $("#cboStores").data('bs.popover').options.content = $('#popoverContent').html();
}
```

And the popover content in the initialization of the popover in the javascript is changed to:

```
$('#popoverContent').html()
```

This way, what you're actually doing is modifying the content of the HTML and then setting the content of the popover to reflect the changes in the HTML.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/87xswem7/12/

Comment: Note that jsfiddle doesn't work, you need to put in $(document).ready(function () { }); and set jsfiddle to "No wrap - in <body>". This works for me http://jsfiddle.net/87xswem7/13/

Comment: It worked just fine for me in the fiddle I provided at the end of my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/87xswem7/12/. I'm glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I know why:

For your fiddle, you already wrapped the JS in the onload:

[image]

However, you do it again:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //...
}
```

There's no need for that. Simply change it to no wrap.

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about this option. +1 for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
setStore = function($s, id, name) {
    //alert("length: " + $s.parents('ul.popup-cbo-menu').find('li.selected').length);
    $s.parents('ul.popup-cbo-menu').find('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
    //alert("length: " + $s.parents('ul.popup-cbo-menu').find('li.selected').length);

    //$s.parent('li').addClass('selected');
    $('#cboStores').val(name);
}
```

rather than

```
function setStore($s, id, name) {
    //alert("length: " + $s.parents('ul.popup-cbo-menu').find('li.selected').length);
    $s.parents('ul.popup-cbo-menu').find('li.selected').removeClass('selected');
    //alert("length: " + $s.parents('ul.popup-cbo-menu').find('li.selected').length);

    //$s.parent('li').addClass('selected');
    $('#cboStores').val(name);
}
```

it solved for me [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/87xswem7/10/)

Comment: Can you explain the difference of defining meanings?

Comment: Hmmm... it is now recognising setStore() function, but why? what is the difference? thanks...